# context.startActivity in broadcast receiver sometimes not working (targetSDK 19 on an SDK 27 device)

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, android-background

I call `startActivity` in an implicit broadcast receiver's `onReceive` function under certain very limited circumstances.

```
Intent transactionIntent = new Intent(context, TransactionActivity.class);
transactionIntent.putExtra(Constants.Extras.ORDER_ID, orderId);
transactionIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
context.startActivity(transactionIntent);
```

I have logs before this line and logs in the `onCreate` function of the activity. Some customers are reporting random instances of this activity not creating itself. I can see in the logs that `startActivity` is called and `onCreate` is not. One of them I know for sure is an Android 8.1 Oreo device. My target SDK is 19 (vast majority are old devices, this is not an app on the Play store). I can also tell the Background activity toggle in the system settings for the app is not switched off so that is not the problem.

What situations can this happen (extreme memory pressure?) and how can I capture it to verify what is going on?

**EDIT:**

The app is not crashing (no crashes logged for this version of the app, and it does nothing but `setContentView` before logging the activity creation). I don't think device sleep is an issue because I am targeting pre M, doze mode etc. doesn't come in to play. The user was also using the app a few seconds before this call to `startActivity` failed, and 30 seconds later they were using the app as well, so that window doesn't seem likely large enough to allow for any kind of sleep or wake lock issues. I also don't think the user could have managed to swipe the app out of memory between the app calling `startActivity` and `onCreate`, this is happening sporadically (for this one user is happened 1 out of 6 times).

The app is a for a busy, mains connected Point of Sale device.

Comment: Is the `context` variable used here the same as the `Context` argument provided in the `onReceive()` call?

Comment: It is David yes, I thought about using the app context, do you think that would make a difference? I can't see anything online that might point to that being an issue but certainly worth a shot.

Comment: No, I don't think so. Using app context shouldn't be necessary here and probably won't make a difference. Is it possible that `TransactionActivity` is crashing in `onCreate()` before it writes your log messages?

Comment: Is it possible that the `BroadcastReceiver` is being called when the device was sleeping, and it wakes up to handle the broadcast `Intent`, but then goes back to sleep before the `Activity` can be launched?

Comment: Thanks David I've addressed those in an edit at the bottom of the question. I am stumped as to how to catch what is going on here!

Comment: I am facing the exact same issue. Has this been resolved? In my case the activity starts randomly, no fixed behaviour can be observed with respect to app running in the background or not running at all.

Comment: @DanielWilson did you find a solution for this?

Comment: I did not! I think the best solution is not to start an activity but to use notifications or work manager tasks instead, the OS is going the direction that this will be totally banned soon

Comment: If the OS is going that way, then I cant do much. Actually my whole app depends on broadcast receiver and activity start. I absolutely cannot do without an activity. Even the background service approach is also being shunned by android team.